# Last remote notification overrides the previous one android

Tags: android, react-native, moengage

I am testing on android 9 and I have observed that if I send two or more notifications I will always have only one notification and that is the last one I sent.

Do you know if this is a known issue? If not then do you know what could cause this issue or where on the native side can I take a look more closely into this?

react-native: 0.61.5

react-native-moengage: 4.1.0 also on 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default MoEngage SDK on Android only shows one notification at any point in time. This behaviour can be changed by enabling multiple notification while initialising the SDK. To enable multiple notifications call the below method on the `MoEngage.Builder` object while initialising the SDK

`setNotificationType(R.integer.notification_type_multiple)`

Answer (score 1):

On the native side to show a notification you use `NotificationManager` and call its `notify(int id, Notification notification)` method. In your case the `id` parameter needs to be unique, for example you can pass `System.currentTimeMillis()` as the `id`, because it overrides notifications with the same `id`.

Comment: Thank you for your response but first I tried what Umang recommended and it worked.